# How can I search an item in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I am doing a school project about a inventory system, and I am facing some problem in programming the `Search` function.

Take an example:

```py
ilist = [ [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [...], ...]
```

I would like to search for `1` and want the list containing `1` to display.

```py
search = input('By user:')
for item in ilist:
  if item == search :
     print(item)
```

It does not work this way and I get this error:

> list index out of range error

Comment: That code won't throw an IndexError. But it won't find anything, either; search is a *string*.

Comment: Try `if int(search) in item`

Answer (score 3):

you have a nested list and are now checking against the list ('1' wont match with [1,2,3,4,5] )

so you have to loop over the list within the list and change input to int:

```
ilist = [ [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]

search = input('By user:')
for item in ilist:
    for i in item:
        if i == int(search):
            print(i)
```

this is building on your way of coding, could be further improved from this

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. `ilist` is a list of lists, and you're comparing `search` to each list
2. Each member in each list is of type `int`, while `search` is of type `str`

In short, change this:

```
if item == search
```

To this:

```
if int(search) in item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to find the element from each `list`

```
search = int(input('By user:'))
for item in ilist:
    if search in item:
        print(item)
```

Comment: `type(search) == 'str'` and `type(item[n]) == 'int'`, so I doubt that this would work.